# Data-binding in JsViews

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender, jsviews

I have a Javascript object literal like

```
test : {
  length: 3,
  text: "Please enter 3 characters"
 }
```

I want to make the text rendered dynamic based on length, something like this

```
test : {
      length: 3,
      text: "Please enter {{:length}} characters"
     }
```

Is there any way to achieve this in JsViews ? I looked at https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/327, but I am not sure if the same approach is applicable in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make a helper format like this

**html**

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <input type="text" data-link="length"/>
  <br/>
  <span> {^{:~format(text, length)}} </span>
</script>
```

**js**

```
var data = {
    length : 3,
    text : "Please enter {0} characters",
}

var _rxMark = /\{(\d+)\}/g;
var helpers = {
    format : function (string) {
        var data = [];
        for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            data[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
        }
        return string.replace(_rxMark, function (substring, argIndex) {
            var result = data[parseInt(argIndex)];
            return result || "";
        });
    }
}

var tmpl = $.templates("#tmpl");

tmpl.link("#result", data, helpers);
```

see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/db83c075/1).

It may also be useful to you here [sample](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/validate/simple).